# should Angular 2 js package be referenced in index.html or dynamically loaded from a folder using System.js?

Tags: angular

How should js files be refereed in angular 2. should they be added to index.html like angular 1. * or dynamically loaded from a folder using System.js ?

Comment: I believe that it is loaded dynamically when you load them via the `import` statement, at least this is what I have seen in the quick tutorials on angular.io

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include it in index.html. It should be loaded by System.js: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart